# FIlenames as variables in list of tibbles in R

Tags: r, list, filenames, tibble

I have several .csv files and I want to read them into a list of tibbles. I also want to add a variable that represents the name of the file from which the data were taken.

I use this code

```
temp = list.files(pattern="^[L]")
```

And now I have all the file names in the temp:

[1] "L03NO.csv" "L04NO.csv" "L18NY.csv" "L19NY.csv" "L20NY.csv" "L21NY.csv"
 [7] "L26NY.csv" "L27NY.csv" "L28NY.csv" "L29NY.csv" "L38NY.csv"

Then I read all the files with these names in the list

```
myfiles = lapply(temp, read_csv)
```

The output list only enumerates the tibbles inside.

How do I add filename as a variable into each tibble?

Comment: `Map(cbind, myfiles, from = names(myfiles))`

Comment: Thank you! It worked with
```Map(cbind, myfiles, from = temp)```